# How can I JSON.stringify a Collection in Dart

Tags: json, dart

How can I made a JSON string out of a collection in dart, as I can do it with Maps. The docs say I can pass a map or a an array into the `JSON.stringify()` method. But there are no Array data type in Dart and passing a collection gives me an exception.

I've a naive workaround, but I wonder if there will be a better way to do this:

```
    String s = '[';
    bool first=true;

    _set.forEach(function(item){
      if (first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        s+=',';
      }
      s += JSON.stringify(item);
    });
    s +=']';
    print(s);
    return s;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing a list works for me:

- in the Dart VM importing `dart-sdk/lib/frog/server/dart_json.dart`
- in Dartium importing `json:dart`

using this code:

```
void main() {
  var list = new List.from(["a","b","c"]);
  print(JSON.stringify(list));
}
```

prints this JSON snippet:

```
["a","b","c"]
```

Doesn't work for new `Set.from(...)` which is expected, given that JSON only deals in maps and lists.

Comment: Why would you expect that Set not work. List and Set are both collection, what would be so hard to convert a Set into an Array, or easely in to a String with the JSON pattern for an array (`[item.toString, item.toString()`])

Comment: I expect this because JSON has no concept of a Set, converting this to JSON would lose the Set semantics. Of course it would be easy to allow any collection to be stringified into JSON, but this would break the current 1:1 mapping between JSON and Dart. I guess Set/Collection support in stringify() is just something that's still missing because Dart is so young -- go ahead and [file an issue](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/) if you want to speed this up :)

Answer (score 13):

In Dart, you can get a JSON `String` out of an `Object` using the `JsonEncoder`'s [`convert`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-convert/JsonEncoder/convert.html) method. Here is an example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final jsonEncoder = JsonEncoder();

  final collection1 = List.from([1, 2, 3]);
  print(jsonEncoder.convert(collection1)); // prints [1,2,3]

  final collection2 = List.from(['foo', 'bar', 'dart']);
  print(jsonEncoder.convert(collection2)); // prints ["foo","bar","dart"]

  final object = {'a': 1, 'b': 2};
  print(jsonEncoder.convert(object)); // prints {"a":1,"b":2}
}
```